# Excel - Removing outliers from horizontal data using IF statements and dynamic threshold

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, outliers

I'm trying to get rid of some outliers from my dataset. Below is a section of my dataset.

```
       13284    13285   13293   13294   13297   13301   13304   13309
Sat1    0.6140  #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    0.0635  #N/A
Sat2    #N/A    #N/A    0.5820  #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A
```

Here's a graph of the entire dataset so you can see what I'm dealing with.
[image]

I want to apply a rule where IF a value in the Sat1 row is less than the last non-#N/A value in the Sat2 row minus that value multiplied by 20% THEN change the Sat1 value to #N/A. So in this example, 0.0635 is way less than 0.5820-(0.5820*0.2) and therefore will be omitted. This would get rid of the first huge dip you see in the graph.

I'm sure an If statement is needed; probably nestled within some other functions but I can't figure out how to deal with the #N/As. The solution needs to be dynamic because I have other datasets (graphs) to filter through too and the #N/As are not always in the same location. Any ideas? Maybe too complicated for Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is as below then -

```
     A       B      C    D         E      F       G       H       I
#1          13284  13285  13293   13294   13297   13301   13304   13309
#2  Sat1   0.6140  #N/A   #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    0.0635  #N/A
#3  Sat2    #N/A   #N/A   0.5820  #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A
```

You can put below formula starting from column C in row#4 -

```
=IF(C2>LOOKUP(2,1/(ISNUMBER($A3:B3)),$A3:B3)*0.8,C2,NA())
```

You can drag this formulla for entire row#4 to derive updated Sat1 row :-)

P.S. - I have converted "Sat2 row minus that value multiplied by 20%" as 80% of Sat2 row.